# Deleted .dvd file, and "Could not open file for writing."

Tags: rendering, video

I just completed my first Blender job. Without thinking, I deleted what I thought was a superfluous .dvd file.

After realizing I rendered my file in black and white instead of RBG, I tried to render my job again but I just get a the warning, "Could not open file for writing." I do have a saved, .blend file. Is it possible to generate another mpeg file from this?

Comment: What file are you getting the error message form? And did blender generate the .dvd?

Comment: Blender did generate the .dvd file, but I don't know what the original file name was. I get the error when I try generating the file from an untitled.blend file.

Comment: I still do not fully understand your question. Why can't you just re-render (this time in color) the video from your original blend? When you say generate a file, are you talking about converting the video to another format, or something else?

Comment: Well, your first question is really what I'm wondering myself. When I try to re-render, it just gave me the error. This is my first time using the software--I assumed the .dvd file I deleted was a critical file used to build the final output. I'm just talking about the files the software generates when I hit render.

Comment: Will you upload the original blend, to a place like [blend exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), something does not seem right.

Comment: To what format of file (or files, in case of an image sequence) are you rendering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could also be a permission problem and maybe the .dvd file has nothing to do with it... double check if blender can write to the output path set for your work (still or movie) in rendering settings...

Comment: That's it exactly Ardito. The file writes perfectly when the permissions are open. Thanks!

Comment: Also, my apologies to all for my incoherence. I was up all night with this dang project.