# Could not open file for writing?

Tags: rendering, video, linux

I have been using blender for a few years and this is the first time I have come across this problem. I am running 2.79 on Ubuntu. I was trying render a short test video for a new project and I came across this error on the top of my blender feed.

"Could not open file for writing"

And occasionally I get the error "Python: RENDER_MT_presets"

There is a triangle caution sign on the left of it. I am trying to write to the same folder of my last 6 videos. I found several videos just saying that I need to change the output source, but that didn't work. I also found this post on the forum.
[Deleted .dvd file, and "Could not open file for writing."](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39389/deleted-dvd-file-and-could-not-open-file-for-writing)
I tried changing the permission for the folder, but again it had no effect. I am now confused by this and am hoping that someone could help.

[image]

Comment: The "Could not open file" error sometimes appears when you delete /move the rendered file and then try to render with that same name to that same location again. Try to change name of the output file.

Comment: Check in compositing or materials if any input nodes require a local texture file.

Comment: I wonder if the space in your folder name is the cause. If you open a terminal window and start blender from there, you should get some extra error info that may help figure out what the problem is. The RENDER_MT_presets error is referring to the preset menu above the render resolution, this would save to `$HOME/.config/blender/2.79/scripts/presets/render/`.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how to check that. I have never had to go into the deeper settings. I'm just curious as to why this was working 2 weeks ago, but now this is giving me this issue?

Comment: You might have relative paths in your input nodes and might moved your blend file or the source images. To check go to the compositing view from scene. To debug precisely, maybe use the toggle system console from window and post the error

Comment: You only need to add at the render output settings on the path location the .blend text

Answer (score 9):

In properties window, go to *Output* tab.
Find *Output* heading within that tab.
Check the *File Extensions* box (which is below the *Output* save path entry).

Comment: Not sure why that worked, but it did. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem, solved by re-linking the render folder location through the *Output* tab in the *Properties Window*, clicked on the folder tab and chose the same folder. Rendered correctly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error just by unchecking the *File Extensions* in *Output* option, then you have to add the extension manually directly in the final file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it turned out to be Linux limiting the number of open files the the process (blender) may use.

Here is an annotated script that fixes the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash
# find the current limit
blenderProcessID="$(pidof blender)"
currentLimit="$(prlimit  -n -p $blenderProcessID | tail -n1 | awk '{print $7}' 2>/dev/null)"

# Find the current number of open files used by blender:
currentOpenFiles="$(lsof -p "$blenderProcessID" | wc -l)"

# Calculate the difference
delta=$((currentOpenFiles - currentLimit))

# If Blender has less files open then the limit, exit.
((delta > 0)) || { echo 'Number of files used by blender is under the current process limit.' >&2; exit 1; } 

# increase the limit by double the delta.
newLimit=$((delta * 2 + currentLimit))
sudo prlimit --nofile="$newLimit" --pid "$blenderProcessID" && echo "Increased open-file limit to $newLimit" >&2
```

The idea here is that each user has a set of default limits that each new process runs under. This is queried and modified with the **ulimit** bash-built-in command.

However, once a process is running, the limits must be changed with the **prlimit** command.

Therefore, if you find you run into this problem often, you might consider changing the default for your user:

```
echo "ulimit -n $newLimit" >> ~/.profile
```

which will take effect after you logout and back in (reboot etc.).